# Buttons list bind to Grid into UserControl (WPF, Linq, Buttons)

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, xaml, data-binding

I'm doing list of buttons based on Linq query.

*UserControl*.cs

```
 public partial class GenerateButtonView : UserControl
 {    
    public GenerateButtonView()
    {
       InitializeComponent();

       List<Button> listOfButtons = new List<Button>();
       for (int x = 0; x <= gb.ListDistinctAutoName().Count; x++)
       {
          Button b = new Button();
          b.Content = "button" + x.ToString();
          listOfButtons.Add(b);               
       }
     }}
```

GenerateButtonModel.cs

```
public class GenerateButtonModel
{
   public List<string> ListDistinctAutoName()
   {
      testViewClassDataContext tv = new testViewClassDataContext();
      List<string> q3 = tv.test_views.Select(i => i.AutoName).Distinct().ToList();               

       return q3;
   }}
```

How can I bind the create list of buttons to my Grid?

*UserControl*.xaml

```
<UserControl.....>
....
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Grid.RowSpan="3">

        </Grid>  

</UserControl>
```

Comment: A Grid has not ItemsSource property that you can a collection of elements to. Why do you want to add the buttons to a Grid? How do you define in which cell the button will be located?

Comment: I can add the buttons to stackpanel or dockpanel, but I don't know how to....

Comment: You should use an ItemsControl. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an `ItemsControl` and bind or set its `ItemsSource` property to the `List<Button>`:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="ic" />
```

---

```
public GenerateButtonView()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    List<Button> listOfButtons = new List<Button>();
    for (int x = 0; x <= gb.ListDistinctAutoName().Count; x++)
    {
        Button b = new Button();
        b.Content = "button" + x.ToString();
        listOfButtons.Add(b);
    }

    ic.ItemsSource = listOfButtons;
}}
```

> My idea is that buttons should be located horizontally with margin between them

Then you could for example use a `StackPanel` as the `ItemsPanel` of the `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="ic">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

You set the `Margin` property of each of the buttons.

Note that the best practice would be to bind the `ItemsSource` property to a collection of data objects and then define the actual UI element (`Button`) in the ItemTemplate:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="ic">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: thank you @mm8! one question -> If I will create DockPanel for example, bind the buttons the same way?

Comment: No, a DockPanel doesn't have any ItemsSource property. It is the same thing there, how you intend to define the docking position of the buttons?

Comment: My idea is that buttons should be located horizontally with margin between them

Comment: If you really need to use panel, then you need to add buttons manually. There is no way to bind panel's childs

Answer (score 0):

You need to add buttons manually to the grid

```
for (int x = 0; x <= gb.ListDistinctAutoName().Count; x++)
{
    Button b = new Button();
    b.Content = "button" + x.ToString();
    listOfButtons.Add(b);
    grid.Children.Add(b);
}
```

or use `ItemsControl` and set list of buttons as a `ItemsSource`